# How to block less while streaming video from tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I want to know how to make my Tornado video streaming code block less so that I don't impact other handers in my web app.

I have some legacy code that I use in Tornado to stream incoming jpegs and show them as video on an html page. My handler looks like this. It's worked well enough for a few years, but lately I've noticed that it is actually a big resource hog. Whenever something calls this handler all other requests slow down dramatically.

```
class VideoAPI(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    '''
    Serves a MJPEG of the images posted from the vehicle.
    '''

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        host = self.get_argument("host")
        port = int(self.get_argument("port"))
        ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
        self.set_header("Content-type", "multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=--frame")
        self.served_image_timestamp = time.time()
        my_boundary = "--frame"
        for frame in live_video_stream(host,port=port):
            interval = .1
            if self.served_image_timestamp + interval < time.time():
                img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tostring()
                self.write(my_boundary)
                self.write("Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n")
                self.write("Content-length: %s\r\n\r\n" % len(img))
                # Serve the image
                self.write(img)
                self.served_image_timestamp = time.time()
                yield tornado.gen.Task(self.flush)
            else:
                yield tornado.gen.Task(ioloop.add_timeout, ioloop.time() + interval)
```

Elsewhere in my app I have code that's somewhat computationally expensive that I can run without hogging the CPU too much. It follows this pattern:

```
class Example(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(3)

    @tornado.concurrent.run_on_executor
    def do_some_stuff(self):
        """Do something that's not asyncio-friendly, and computationally slow"""
        return something

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        result = yield self.do_some_stuff()
        self.write(result)
```

Assuming this second example is the most efficient pattern for streaming video, how can I convert the video handler to look more like this? I inherited the video handler code from someone else, and I don't really know how to replicate the loop part. For example, should I leave the loop in the function that runs on the executor? Should I keep it in the `@tornado.gen.coroutine` decorated method? I should do something entirely different?

Comment: What **CPU** do you run this on? If you have multiple **cores** you can spin-up multiple Tornado instances so other handlers can be served by **idle** instances.

Comment: If latency is not very important you can increase the interval variable to something like **0.2**.

Comment: I have a 2015 Mac Pro with 4 cores. So yeah, I guess I could put Tornado behind a gunicorn server, or some equivalent, but I'd like to reserve that as a plan B. I'm hoping there is a faster way to stream data by just optimizing my code. My refresh rate is important because the video is used to drive a remote control car, so 0.2 is too slow.

Answer (score 2):

You need to identify the expensive parts of the code and move them to other threads; leave the rest of the code in the coroutine (which is required for making Tornado calls like `self.write`). For example, my guess is that the main problem is the line

```
img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tostring()
```

To move this to another thread (using more modern tornado idioms than the run_on_executor decorator), put it in a function and run it like this:

```
def expensive_fn():
    return cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tostring()

img = yield ioloop.run_in_executor(None, expensive_fn)
```

If the problem is `for frame in live_video_stream(host,port=port)` then you'll need to do a more extensive refactoring to move away from the generator pattern so it can be iterated in a separate thread.